# TestSSLServer Results

Tags: tls

I ran TestSSLServer.exe (from http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) against a web server in my organization.  The results seemed self explanatory save for one section I'm not sure how to interpret.  Here are the full results of the scan:

```
C:\temp>TestSSLServer.exe 1.2.3.4 443
Supported versions:
SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1.0
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  SSLv2
     RC4_128_WITH_MD5
     RC4_128_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5
  SSLv3
     RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
     DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
    DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  (TLSv1.0: idem)
----------------------
Server certificate(s):
  b9f26b0aaa19e8c45ad1571adb9fe818dbbe7fab: CN=CONTOSO, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY,
O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, S=MyState, C=US
----------------------
Minimal encryption strength:     weak encryption (40-bit)
Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
BEAST status: protected
CRIME status: protected
```

Does anybody know what **(TLSv1.0:  idem)** indicates?  Although TLSv1.0 is listed under "Supported versions", my best guess is that TLSv1.0 may be supported, but the server doesn't provide any ciphers that may be used, effectively rendering TLSv1.0 unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

As [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idem), in its infinite wisdom, "*idem*" is a Latin word and means "the same":

> ***Id.*** (masculine and neuter) and ***ead.*** (feminine) (Latin, short for ***idem*** and ***eadem***, "the same") are the terms used to denote the previously cited source

In this case, this means that the list of cipher suites for TLS 1.0 is strictly identical to the list for SSL 3.0, so it is not repeated in the tool output.